# Proof of an equation in a Hilbert space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that $$(x,y) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lVert x+\alpha^k y \rVert^2 \alpha^k = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lVert x + e^{i\phi}y \rVert^2 e^{i\phi} d \phi$$
>
> where $x, y \in H$ (Hilbert Space) and $\alpha \neq \pm1$ any $n$th root of unity.

So I solved the first equation by manipulating the sum and using properties of the norm and the inner product.

For the second one, my approach would be to do a complex integration, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lVert x + e^{i\phi}y \rVert^2 e^{i\phi} d \phi = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \lVert x + zy \rVert^2 d \phi.$$

Im not sure how to follow up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^\pi_{-\pi} (x+ e^{i\phi} y, x+e^{i\phi}y)  e^{i\phi}\ d\phi = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} [(x, x)+(y, y)+ (x, y)e^{-i\phi}+( y, x)e^{i\phi}]e^{i\phi}\ d\phi
\end{align}